# How to add some more scroll at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page where the lowest element in the page doesn't have enough page for it to be scrolled to the top of the screen.

How do I add just enough screen(white space) at the bottom of the page so that the lowest 'post' can be scrolled to the top?

Comment: you can check with javascript height of element that you need to get fully visible and add padding to body. this way you will always have just enough space at bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript to obtain window's height with something like

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

Then get that last post's height with something like that

```
var height = document.getElementById('foo').offsetHeight;
```

Subtract element's height from windows height and apply your result as a padding-bottom to that element.

Answer (score 2):

Use padding: `body{padding-bottom: 500px;}`

Comment: What if 500 px isn't enough? I want it to vary according to the screen size.

Comment: @haky_nash from your showed code, i see, that there is less than 500px in height, so it will be good.

Comment: How do I add just enough screen(white space) at the bottom of the page so that the lowest 'post' can be scrolled to the top?

Answer (score 0):

set some `min-height` value for your body:

```
body{
     min-height:1200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add bottom margin of the element, or you can create an empty div tag at last with some height

Comment: How do I add *just enough* screen(white space) at the bottom of the page so that the lowest 'post' can be scrolled to the top?

Comment: set the height of the last empty div (total height of page - height of last post) if it helps.